# Use FromQuery model binder in output formatter

Tags: c#, .net-core, model-binding

I have a custom OutputFormatter in my .net core project. In there I want to use some info inside the querystring of the initial request.

Inside the controller this is nicely done with the FromQuery modelbinder, giving me an object to work with. I would like to have this object (model) in my output formatter as well.

Can I somehow call FromQuery as an instance or such, so I can pass in the HttpContext or the querystring even, to get the model?

```
public override Task WriteResponseBodyAsync(OutputFormatterWriteContext context)
    {
        // Want a model from my querystring here
    }
```

Comment: This looks like an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). [FromQuery](https://github.com/aspnet/Mvc/blob/65af12f1f575fdaee893e0232416df29bb83d7fa/src/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Core/FromQueryAttribute.cs) is a metadata attribute and its instance has no functionality

Comment: Provide a [mcve] of what you have so far to help demonstrate what it is you are trying to achieve.

Comment: Not sure if adding more sample code would clearify my question. Thing is that I now use the querystring from the httprequest to get the data but I would like to have this done automatically like using the FromQuery attribute in a controller.

Comment: Why don't you get the information in the controller and include it in the output object the one that is sent in the `context.Object`? You so or so do custom formatting so only what you decide will be sent out.

Comment: It seems to me like that is a bad practise. You want your controller to be clean and return the actual response you expect. If I send the query info along, I would need to handle this in other output formatters as well, the default JSON output formatter included.

To clearify: I want info from the querystring only to use in one specific output formatter (in my case an Excel outpur formatter). It is not needed elsewhere

Comment: Can I rephrase the question to: How to get object instead of manual parsing of `context.HttpContext.Request.Query` ?

Comment: Yes, you could. I was referring to 'model' because you have 'ModelBinders' like the FromQuery model binder when using a controller.

Comment: Use `HttpContext.Items` to pass object and `CanWriteResult` in `OutputFormatter` to define if it can process the object. `HttpContext.Items` is cleaned at the end of request and it'll be more performant than make model binder do the job twice

Comment: What is in HttpContext.Items and how is that better than just using the query collection from the request? Adding some additional info; I want to use the model also because it contains some default values which I need to define twice when using the query collection.

Comment: `HttpContext.Items` is a dictionary acessible in controller and formatter. You can put a binded object (with default values) in there       `HttpContext.Items["data"] = objectFromQuery;` and read in formatter `context.HttpContext.Items["data"] as QueryObjectType`

Answer (score 1):

Use `HttpContext.Items`. The objects placed in there will be cleaned up at the end of request. And you can pass even more with it, defaulted values or changed values (probably it can be a dangerous point if you are going to change binded object)

```
// GET api/values
[HttpGet]
public ActionResult Get([FromQuery] QData data)
{
    HttpContext.Items["data"] = data;
    .......
    return Ok(....);
}
```

Also you can have multiple formatters for different types of requests.

```
public class Formatter : OutputFormatter
{
    public override bool CanWriteResult(OutputFormatterCanWriteContext context)
    {
        return context.HttpContext.Items["data"] is QData;
    }
    public override Task WriteResponseBodyAsync(OutputFormatterWriteContext context)
    {
        var incoming = context.HttpContext.Items["data"] as QData;
        .......
    }
}
```

The same way you can put any other object in `Items` and work with it in formatter. In case of other object it can be more generic and stable solution as it relies on specific structure.

Comment: Nice. This seems like an acceptable sollution! Thanks.

Comment: Good. As a sugestion: maybe, it will be better, if you'll not pass the query object as it is, but form and pass some kind of `FormatterHint` object, that will be more general approach. Anyway it is you to decide